# Seach a given text in table and should show pass if exist

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My problem is, I have a dynamic table , and I want to search if given string exist in Table. If it exist then it is passed , otherwise fail. My code is

```
Boolean isPresent = false;  
WebElement mytable = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div/table")); //To locate rows of table.
List < WebElement > rows_table = mytable.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //To calculate no of rows In table.
int rows_count = rows_table.size(); //Loop will execute for all the rows of the table
for (int row = 0; row < rows_count; row++) {
    //To locate columns(cells) of that specific row.
    List < WebElement > Columns_row = rows_table.get(row).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
    //To calculate no of columns(cells) In that specific row.  
    int columns_count = Columns_row.size();  
    //System.out.println("Number of cells In Row " + row + " are " + columns_count);  
    //Loop will execute till the last cell of that specific row.
    for (int column = 0; column < columns_count; column++) {
        //To retrieve text from the cells.
        celltext = Columns_row.get(column).getText();
        System.out.println("Cell Value Of row number " + row + " and column num ber " + column + " Is " + celltext);
        if (celltext.equals("dfsahdfakjfhka")) {
            System.out.println("passed on: " + celltext);
            isPresent=true;
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("failed on: " + celltext);
            isPresent=false;
        }
    }
}
if (isPresent==true) {
    Assert.assertFalse(true);
}
else{
    Assert.assertFalse(false);
}
```

When it runs. No error is showing.Actually my table is nott having the value ""dfsahdfakjfhka". .Passed and Failed message is showing correct and also boolean valeu 'isPresent' returns false.But assert is not working here

Comment: Refer this section. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop though all the tr and td, you can just get the text of whole table and then see if your desired text is in it or not.

```
@Test
public void verifyTableContainsText(){
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp");
    WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.id("customers"));
    Assert.assertTrue(isTableContainsText(table, "Germany"));
    Assert.assertFalse(isTableContainsText(table, "India"));

}

public boolean isTableContainsText(WebElement table, String text){
    if (table.getText().contains(text)){
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Its not working.I always return false. I have given xpath instead of id.Please suggest

Comment: @Vishnu you mean the above example is not working or code you have written for you application is not working?

Comment: Thanks ...Gaurang..Its working fine....I did some mistake in my code...Thanks again